# Separation of graphics card and motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

This is somewhat of a theoretical question. Would it be possible to have a display that has a graphics card imbeded then with wifi or some other wireless tech attach this screen to a computer and use it like a regular monitor or would the graphics card have to be physically connected to the computer. I know the tech to do this doesn't actually exist im just wondering.

Comment: It kind of does exist. That's more or less what USB monitors do https://www.amazon.com/AOC-e1659Fwu-1366x768-Brightness-3-0-Powered/dp/B00CMKOVMO/ref=sr_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1487253569&sr=1-1-spons&keywords=usb+monitor&psc=1

Comment: the big issues are bandwidth and latency, especially for heavy tasks like software video decoding or gaming that relies heavily on CPU. As networking standards improve, it is possible that these issues will be reigned in somewhat.